# .Net Standard 2.0 and .Net Framework 4.6.1 vs 4.7.2

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.6.1

Microsoft, in a lot of places, says that code built for .Net Standard 2.0 can run on .NET Framework 4.6.1 but really should be run on .NET Framework 4.7.2.

This does not impact building our DLLs (it's a commercial library) that we provide via NuGet, but is just a recommendation to the people using the DLLs about the version their app should use, correct?

(I don't see how the DLLs are built differently based on that framework difference, but figure it's better to ask)

Comment: Can you cite one of those places? I have never heard of that. But yes, you are correct. 4.6.1 is enough.

Comment: starting with [.net 4.7.2, you don't have the additional system dlls next to your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484849/1466046). So best is to target 4.8, which is fully 2.0 compatible and also the last classic .net framework version.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes I agree with that. And like your suggestion of 4.8. But my root question remains - do I need to build all my DLLs twice, once for 4.6.1 and once for 4.7.2? Or do I build once for 4.6.1 because the 4.7.2 or 4.8 setting is in our customer's setting for their app and the compiling for out .cs to a .dll is identical across both?

Comment: Like I commented under other questions you posted earlier, experiments can be the only way to get most of it. 1) Your netstandard2.0 project only needs to be built once. 2) You have to ship a NuGet package (so that all consumers net461 or net472 will get the right dependencies from NuGet). 3) If you ship a single assembly, well, you break your consumers on net461 as all necessary dependencies are missing.

Comment: @LexLi I've found from painful experience over the years that finding a working solution from experimentation leaves giant bugs in for configurations different than the one I tested for. That's why I ask - from many people comes what should work for all situations.

Comment: no, only build your lib for .net standard 2.0 and the customers have to decide if they are ok, to have the additional DLLs.