# VS2017 Setup project for .NET 4.7.2

Tags: deployment, installation, visual-studio-2017

Having configured a Setup project for my .NET 4.7.2 codebase the Detected Dependencies shows up with a netstandard.dll. 
Is there anyway to tell where this might be coming from?
Again it's just an entire 4.7.2 based code with that target Framework chosen.
The Prerequisites Page has the 4.7.2 chosen and the Launch condition has 4.7.2.

What could be causing the netstandard.dll to be included in the project output?

Comment: do you consume a nuget package that only supports .net standard 2.0 and not normal .net framework 4.x?

Comment: I've checked all that but I'm now searching thru the project.assets.json at the moment to see what packages are referenced since you really can't see all the dependencies.

Comment: So yes -- It looks like in the project.assets.json I can see the reference to the netstandard.dll: Some nuget pkg has a reference to System.Buffers/4.4.0  which causes the netstandard.dll to get included in the project dependencies.

Comment: ok, now you know the cause why the dll is required.

Comment: crazy -- why can't those who target netstandard 2.0 also target 4.7? They are compatible as far as I know.

Comment: 4.7 is treated as .net standard 2.0 compatible and can consume the lib so no extra target for classic .net 4.x is added only if lib creator still wants to support 4.5.x (which is not ns2.0 compatible) they add it. And if you would [target 4.6, you would get a lof of system dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484849/1466046), so 4.7.2 is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be causing the netstandard.dll to be included in the
>   project output?

First, thanks to **magicandre1981** for all his help.

You have referenced a net standard nuget packages in your Net Framework 4.7.2 project. And because of the special nature of the package, it needs to refer to `netstandard.dll` as a runtime environment.

**Although** **Net Frameowork 4.7.2** optimizes the build output file, so `netstandard.dll` cannot be shown in the project outputpath, but in fact the project will still use it at runtime.

But for the setup project, there is no such feature. Using the netstandard nuget package, all references will be displayed in Detected Dependencies including `netstandard.dll`.

**In addition**, `Net Standard 2.0` is compatible with `Net Frameowork 4.7.2`, and you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).