# Why is .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Standard 2.0 listed as dependencies in NuGet?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.6.1

I found this when looking at a NuGet package.

Why are these 2 special? What about all the other .NET framework and .NET Standard versions?

[image]

Comment: If you unzip the .nupkg you can see it has assemblies for .NET Standard and .NET Framework in its lib directory. The dependencies listed just map to those listed in the .nuspec file in the .nupkg file.

Comment: .net 4.6.1 is also able to consume .net standard 2.0 libs with the [side effect to have may system dlls next to your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484849/1466046). adding .net 4.6.1 as target fixe it, here you don't see the libs.

Comment: ok, you are the owner of the package. and in WaveFileManipulator.csproj you defined TargetFrameworks for netstandard2.0 and net461 and so **dotnet pack** creates nuspec file with both frameworks to avoid the DLL issue I already posted in my 1st comment

Comment: @MattWard but why does it say "No dependencies" below?

Comment: The .nuspec just has the dependency parent root xml element, for .NET 4.6.1 and .NET Standard 2.0, but no child elements, so nuget.org shows No dependencies.