# Install .NET Standard version of a multi-target Nuget from a .NET 4.6.2 application?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

Is it possible from a .NET 4.6.2 application to prefer .NET Standard version installation of a multi-target Nuget?

I have a .NET 4.6.2 application which is using a Nuget package built for both .NETFramework 4.6.2 and .NETStandard 2.0

When looking into the .csproj project file I can see this:

```
<Reference Include="CompanyAcme.TheNugetPackage.Client, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\TheNugetPackage.Client.2.1.4\lib\net462\CompanyAcme.TheNugetPackage.Client.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Which makes me think that my .NET 4.6.2 application is using the .NET 4.6.2 version of the Nuget package.

Comment: why do you want to do this? It is better to use the .net framework version of a lib to avoid [DLL issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484849/1466046)

Comment: I want to know if it's possible, I have a special situation where the .NET standard version of the nuget package doesn't have an old dependency which I can't include in my application.

Comment: as said, .net 4.6.x has those dependency issues, so you get more DLL in output. Microsoft added netfx config back  to several libs to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this filthy hack, but I'd certainly think twice before doing it

```
<PackageReference Include="Prism.Core" ExcludeAssets="Compile" GeneratePathProperty="true"> <Version>7.1.0.431</Version> </PackageReference>
<Reference Include="Prism"> <HintPath>$(PkgPrism_Core)lib\netstandard2.0\Prism.dll</HintPath> </Reference>
```

From https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/a-better-way-to-override-references-with-packagereference/