# How can I use netstandard2 using .net Framework 4.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I'm trying to install the package WebSocketSharp.Standard but I getting installing error.

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'WebSocketSharp.Standard 1.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly
> references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> Install-Package WebSocketSharp.Standard -Version 1.0.3
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I download the NuGet and extract and I check the library only the netstandard2.0
[image]

how can I use the package in my current project? Im using VS2013.

Comment: no, .net 4.6.1 is first somehow compatible .net framework version that can consume .net standard 2.0 libs, but you get [additional system dlls in output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484849/1466046). So best is to use .net 4.8 as it is the last classic .net framework version.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I also tried the .net 4.8 and  same error occurring.

Comment: ok, VS2013 is too old. You need 2017 or 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net standard 2.0 support works starting with .net framework 4.6.1, but you get a lot of [system DLLs next to your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484849/1466046). So use .net 4.8 and not 4.6.x.

The [minimum requirement to use .net standard libs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-standard-libraries-and-visual-studio) is to use Visual Studio 2015 (with the update 3 + a [special hotfix](https://aka.ms/netstandard-build-support-netfx)), but it is better to use VS2017 or 2019:

> If you only need to consume .NET Standard 2.0 libraries in your
> projects, you can also do that in Visual Studio 2015. However, you
> need [NuGet client 3.6 or higher installed](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

So your VS2013 is too old.